# How to join 3 entities with jpql springboot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpql

I have this query in jpql but it is returning an error, when I do it with 2 entities it works, but with 3 entities it returns an error. I think it's a syntax error.

Repository

```
public interface CarsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cars, Long>{
    
    @Query("SELECT new application.dto.GetAllCarsDto(c.timestampRegister, c.fuel, c.year, c.num_doors,"
            + " c.color, e.name_brand, p.modelId, p.name, p.cash) FROM Cars c JOIN c.model e JOIN e.brand p")
    public List<GetAllCarsDto> getJoinInformation();
    
}
```

Comment: the syntax is `a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id` also the new  is your query looks very suspicious, i am unfamiliar with that, can you verify if your database supports it

Comment: I managed to solve it, the correct syntax was this: @Query("SELECT new application.dto.GetAllCarsDto(c.timestampRegister, c.fuel, c.year, c.num_doors,"
            + " c.color, p.modelId, p.name, p.cash, a.name_brand) FROM Cars c JOIN c.model p JOIN p.brand a")

Comment: So answer your question and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, the correct syntax was this:

```
@Query("SELECT new application.dto.GetAllCarsDto(c.timestampRegister, c.fuel, c.year, c.num_doors," + " c.color, p.modelId, p.name, p.cash, a.name_brand) FROM Cars c JOIN c.model p JOIN p.brand a")
```